# Unable to open my android background application (Xamarin) on receipt of Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a Xamarin Android application. On receipt of push notification I am able to open the application if the application is alive and is in foreground. However, the application won't open up if it is in the background or is killed.

Already followed the Xamarin guidelines as stated in the page below but the provided code doesn't work either.
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/notifications/remote-notifications-with-fcm/

I want to take action (read open) on receipt of FCM push notification. Can do it successfully if the application is already open. Am I missing something? The details are as follows

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver" android:exported="false" />
    <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" android:exported="true" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

FirebaseInstanceIdService Implementation

```
[Service]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" })]
public class MyFirebaseIIDService : FirebaseInstanceIdService
{
    const string TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";
    public override void OnTokenRefresh()
    {
        var refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token;
        Log.Debug(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
        SendRegistrationToAppServer(refreshedToken);
    }


    void SendRegistrationToAppServer(string token)
    {
        // Add custom implementation here as needed.

        var android_id = Android.OS.Build.Serial;
        App.AccessCode(token, android_id);
    }

}
```

FirebaseMessagingService Implementation

```
    [Service]
[IntentFilter(new [] { "com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" })]
public class MyFCMListenerService: FirebaseMessagingService {
 Intent intent;

 public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message) {
  Thread thread = new Thread(() => {
   Log.Debug("MyGcmListenerService", "Message: thread");
   PushHandler pushHandler = PushHandler.GetPushHander();
   pushHandler.OnReceiveNewNotification(msg, pushType.ToString());

  });
  thread.Start();
 }
}
```

Package.config

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="AndHUD" version="1.2.0" targetFramework="MonoAndroid60" />
  <package id="Plugin.CurrentActivity" version="1.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="SQLite.Net.Core-PCL" version="3.1.1" targetFramework="MonoAndroid60" />
  <package id="SQLite.Net-PCL" version="3.1.1" targetFramework="MonoAndroid60" />
  <package id="Xam.Plugin.Connectivity" version="3.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xam.Plugin.DeviceInfo" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable" version="25.4.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations" version="25.4.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat" version="25.4.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI" version="25.4.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils" version="25.4.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Design" version="25.4.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment" version="25.4.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Media.Compat" version="25.4.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Transition" version="25.4.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v4" version="25.4.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat" version="25.4.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView" version="25.4.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter" version="25.4.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.Palette" version="25.4.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView" version="25.4.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable" version="25.4.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Build.Download" version="0.4.7" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Firebase.Common" version="42.1021.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Firebase.Iid" version="42.1021.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging" version="42.1021.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Forms" version="2.3.4.270" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base" version="42.1021.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement" version="42.1021.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Tasks" version="42.1021.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
</packages>
```

Also, if I use the prescribed configuration `FirebaseApp.InitializeApp(this);`
then unable to open the application even when in foreground. To solve the problem, have used
`google-services.json`

I am doing this for configuration

```
var options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .SetApplicationId("1:******:*****")
            .SetApiKey("*******-a6-cEUkjxB6EqiO9zmkNcmu")
            //.SetDatabaseUrl("Firebase-Database-Url")
            .SetGcmSenderId("******")
            .Build();

            var firebaseApp = FirebaseApp.InitializeApp(this, options);
            // Generate token in background thread
            Task.Run(() => {
                var instanceID = FirebaseInstanceId.Instance;
                instanceID.DeleteInstanceId();
                var iid1 = instanceID.Token;
                var iid2 = instanceID.GetToken("*****", Firebase.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging.InstanceIdScope);
            });
```

Comment: Didn't find any obvious error in your code, what is your `PushHandler`?  Did you try the official demo [Android FCM Remote Notifications](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/Firebase/FCMNotifications)?

Comment: yes i tried official demo but ,the demo its not working properly in background. Push handler    have some function for modify push according to data.

Answer (score 1):

After wasting time in days i figure out an alternative for receiving push in background and handle or modify it

```
public override void HandleIntent(Intent p0)
```

this function is called every time foreground and background but after killing the this wont't work.